# jQuery Deferreds with Chained Saves, Unified Result

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have two objects, `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`.  I want to save `ObjectB` only after `ObjectA` is done, but I want to return a promise which wraps the result of both of them.

Here's my first hack at it to show the functionality that I want.  This function works fine it's just ugly and surely there's a better way.

*Functions `saveObjectA` and `saveObjectB` both return `$.post()` promises.*

```
saveAAndBSequentially: function () {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    saveObjectA().done(function () {
        saveObjectB().done(function () {
            dfd.resolve();
        }).fail(function () {
            dfd.reject(); 
        });
    }).fail(function () {
        dfd.reject(); 
    });

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

I'd just use `$.when` and add a `done` callback on `saveObjectA` to trigger `saveObjectB`, but the deferred for `saveObjectB` doesn't exist yet so I don't believe I can use `$.when` on it right away.

Ideas on how to solve this is a more elegant manner are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.pipe()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) does exactly the task you have handcoded:

```
var saveAAndBSequentially = function () {
    return saveObjectA().pipe(function () {
        return saveObjectB();
    });
};
```

Comment: Fantastic.  See, I knew there had to be a better way.  Glad to see it's so simple.  Thank you!